# How to pass parameter on 'vagrant up' and have it in the scope of Vagrantfile?

Tags: ruby, command-line, vagrant, parameter-passing

I'm looking for a way to pass parameter to Chef cookbook like:

```
$ vagrant up some_parameter
```

And then use `some_parameter` inside one of the Chef cookbooks.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You cannot pass any parameter to vagrant. The only way is to use environment variables

```
MY_VAR='my value' vagrant up
```

And use `ENV['MY_VAR']` in recipe.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried https://gist.github.com/4435297 and I can get user input, but no idea how to pass it into Chef cookbook. Now will try combine this with ENV

Comment: You can access that ENV var also in the Vagrantfile and put it into the chef.json hash (see http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/provisioners/chef_solo.html#json_configuration)

Comment: Yes, that is more convenient.

Comment: The author of vagrant himself says to use environment variables: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2064

Comment: in powershell you should use something like that
$Env:MY_VAR='my value' | vagrant up

Comment: The other answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31070025/33204 should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 78):

You also can include the *GetoptLong* Ruby library that  allows you to parse command line options.

**Vagrantfile**

```
require 'getoptlong'

opts = GetoptLong.new(
  [ '--custom-option', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ]
)

customParameter=''

opts.each do |opt, arg|
  case opt
    when '--custom-option'
      customParameter=arg
  end
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
             ...
    config.vm.provision :shell do |s|
        s.args = "#{customParameter}"
    end
end
```

Then, you can run :

```
$ vagrant --custom-option=option up
$ vagrant --custom-option=option provision
```

<sup>Note: Make sure that the custom option is specified **before** the vagrant command to avoid an invalid option validation error.</sup>

More information about the library [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/getoptlong/rdoc/GetoptLong.html).

Comment: Have you actually tried this and confirmed to have it working? For I have tried unsuccessfully with the `optparse` library - and therefore I am a bit skeptical this would work.

Comment: I'm using it all day since I posted. It works very well ! What's your problem ?

Comment: It seems that the options are not listed in the `opts` not processed:  

    `vagrant --custom-option=option destroy -f`

    `vagrant: invalid option -- f`

Comment: Yes, this works, and imho is more elegant than the first answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGauthier Are the options that are matched in the "opts.each do" block destroyed, i.e. vagrant isn't confused by them afterwards?

Comment: @BenjaminGauthier The docs say "The empty option -- (two minus symbols) is used to end option processing.". So `vagrant --custom-option=option -- up` should be enough

Comment: This fails when you do `vagrant provision --provision-with`

Comment: This seems to work with Vagrant 1.8.7, including the standard `--provision-with` option after the custom one:  `vagrant  --custom-option=foo -- --provision-with=shell  up` (note the use of `--` to stop processing custom options).  More testing needed though.

Comment: Was anyone able to away with out using `vagrant -- destroy -f` seems that now the `-f` doesn't pass the force flag at all, still need to type `[y/N]`.

I got it working with a default parameters when running `vagrant up` but the `destroy` requires `--` any ideas?

Comment: See here for a solution how to add the native Vagrant option, which would remove the problem with e.g. `-f`: https://gist.github.com/ProxiBlue/0b977416f6c6d20c4f7bb562a9ae64ad

Comment: Invalid option issue can be fixed by adding  some try catch logic.
`begin
require 'getoptlong'

opts = GetoptLong.new(
  [ '--custom-option', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ]
)

customParameter=''

opts.each do |opt, arg|
  case opt
    when '--custom-option'
      customParameter=arg
  end
end
rescue StandardError => boom

end`

Comment: As reported in [this issue in Vagrant](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/2064), this solution does not seem to work with all versions of Vagrant and Ruby.

Comment: This does not work with Vagrant 2 anymore. It does not accept any parameters beside its own.

Answer (score 24):

It is possible to read variables from ARGV and then remove them from it before proceeding to configuration phase. It feels icky to modify ARGV but I couldn't find any other way for command-line options.

#### Vagrantfile

```
# Parse options
options = {}
options[:port_guest] = ARGV[1] || 8080
options[:port_host] = ARGV[2] || 8080
options[:port_guest] = Integer(options[:port_guest])
options[:port_host] = Integer(options[:port_host])

ARGV.delete_at(1)
ARGV.delete_at(1)

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # Create a forwarded port mapping for web server
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: options[:port_guest], host: options[:port_host]

  # Run shell provisioner
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision.sh", :args => "-g" + options[:port_guest].to_s + " -h" + options[:port_host].to_s
```

#### provision.sh

```
port_guest=8080
port_host=8080

while getopts ":g:h:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        g)
            port_guest="$OPTARG" ;;
        h)
            port_host="$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I always get the error _An invalid option was specified_. Doing `puts ARGV` displays correct array after removal of extra custom arguments.

Comment: Same here, it does not work... I put a `puts "#{ARGV}"` line in `vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb` and it prints that line before the removal of the relevant args in the Vagrantfile, thus meaning that the removal is futile as the ARGV is passed to the validator that outputs `An invalid option was specified` before any operations can take place on ARGV.

Answer (score 9):

@benjamin-gauthier 's GetoptLong solution is really neat, fits in with the ruby and vagrant paradigm well.

It however, needs one extra line to fix clean handling of the vagrant arguments, such as `vagrant destroy -f`.

```
require 'getoptlong'

opts = GetoptLong.new(
  [ '--custom-option', GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ]
)

customParameter=''

opts.ordering=(GetoptLong::REQUIRE_ORDER)   ### this line.

opts.each do |opt, arg|
  case opt
    when '--custom-option'
      customParameter=arg
  end
end
```

which allows this block of code to pause when the custom options are processed.
so now,
`vagrant --custom-option up --provision`
or
`vagrant destroy -f`
are cleanly handled.

Hope this helps,

Comment: This helped a lot, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    class Username
        def to_s
            print "Virtual machine needs you proxy user and password.\n"
            print "Username: " 
            STDIN.gets.chomp
        end
    end

    class Password
        def to_s
            begin
            system 'stty -echo'
            print "Password: "
            pass = URI.escape(STDIN.gets.chomp)
            ensure
            system 'stty echo'
            end
            pass
        end
    end

    config.vm.provision "shell", env: {"USERNAME" => Username.new, "PASSWORD" => Password.new}, inline: <<-SHELL
        echo username: $USERNAME
        echo password: $PASSWORD
SHELL
    end
end
```

Comment: This is a good solution but can you show how to use this non-interactively? Is it possible to pipe the args for example?